# How do I forcefully pull an image from the next page to the bottom of current page?

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

I have the following code:

```
Concretely, the algorithm works as follows: Given an n x m grid with 'k' processes, we split up the grid horizontally into 'k' chunks, where each process is responsible for its own chunk. Each chunk is padded with extra halo regions at the top and bottom (with the exception of the topmost and bottom-most chunks -- these will have exactly one extra halo region). We then use MPI interface to allow processes to exchange halo regions with each other and compute the stencil algorithm on their respective chunks. 


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0cm 0},clip,scale=0.4]{halo}
    \caption{Halo exchange between 3 processes using Row Decomposition}
    \label{fig:9-stars stencil}
\end{figure}
```

My page looks like this:

[image]

I want to pull the image up to the bottom of Page 1. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The picture (plus its caption) doesn't fit in page 1, thus LaTeX throws it to the next page (and leaves a large empty space in page 1 because of `H`). You need to resize the picture or the text to make it fit.

Comment: @Phelype ok, thanks - I will try cropping the image. Do you know of any other comands that might be useful?

Comment: scaling it down seemed to do the trick

Comment: the whole point of the `figure` enviornment is to allow the figure to float to avoid white space at page breaks, `[H]` disables floating so forces bad white space at page breaks.

Comment: There's not much you can do here, really. LaTeX doesn't have enough room to put the picture, so it goes to the next page (different of, say, Word, which you can make a picture overflow the margins). Personally, I wouldn't bother and would leave the picture in the second page, where it fits. I would then replace `\begin{figure}[H]`  by `\begin{figure}[ht]` so that it doesn't make that block of white space.

Comment: Try to insert image one paragraph earlier in text and for it  use placeholder option `[b]`. If you draw image for example with `tikz`, than reduce space between grids.

Comment: We could do it (negative \vspace), but it would be wrong.